# Stream encode hevc annex b format file

Tags: hevc

I have a files of hevc annex b format,and I want to simulate streaming mode without any wrapper or container. It is possible? Which decoder and player needed?

Comment: Is this tagged correctly?  That is to say is the target an embedded system, or are you simply embedding video in a web-site?  Questions seeking recommendations or about general computing software are off-topic.  You question needs to be about _code_ and _software development_.  It is not clear that that is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the hevc annex b format file then you need an HEVC decoder.
VLC player support it, you can try to play.